# Multiple dispatch on multiple parametric types

Tags: julia

In Julia, can I achieve the behavior:

```
f(a::String, b::Int) = false
f(b::Int, a::String) = false
f(a::Int, b::Int) = a+b
f(a::String, b::String) = "woohoo!"
```

Using parametric types for the first two functions? Something like:

f(a::T, b::S) where {T!=S} = false

Or something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "computations" you're allowed to do on the types in a `where` statement are very limited. Basically just subtyping, e.g., `T<:AbstractFloat`. You can look into `@generated` functions if you need more sophisticated type computations, but beware some people go crazy and use them where other techniques would be better. There are compile-time and code-size advantages to writing code in a way that the compiler can reason about, for example in the answer from user2891936.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you are looking for.  Julia will always dispatch to the least ambiguous method.

```
f(a::T,b::S) where {T,S} = T==S
f(a::T,b::T) where {T<:Number} = a+b
f(a::T,b::T) where {T<:String} = "woohoo!"
```

Comment: these were more simple examples, but what you're saying is that it is not possible to impose extra constraints on the `where` statement?

Comment: What he is saying that the way to do what you want is to define additional methods. Those three lines of code do exactly what you request.

Comment: @MatíasGuzmánNaranjo, right, the "computations" you're allowed to do on the types in a `where` statement are very limited. Basically just subtyping, e.g., `T<:AbstractFloat`. You can look into `@generated` functions if you need more sophisticated type computations, but beware some people go crazy and use them where other techniques would be better. There are compile-time and code-size advantages to writing code in a way that the compiler can reason about.

Comment: @tholy this was my question, could you post it as a reply so I can mark it as closed?